# Make java compiler output type inference information

Tags: java, generics, javac, type-inference

Is it possible to get `javac` to output information about the types it's inferring for method invocations?

For example, I want to know what is inferred for the formal type `T` in the **invocation** of `bar`.

```
private static <T> void bar() { ... }
public void foo() {
  bar();
}
```

I was exploring `javac -Xprint` and friends, but can't find anything that exposes this level of detail.

---

**EDIT** Example. I didn't want to put this up originally because it'll complicate answers. I'm primarily interested in getting debug info out of `javac`. Anyway, this was the motivating example:

```
public class Scratch {
  private static <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) throws T {
    throw (T) t; // Warning: Type safety: Unchecked cast from Throwable to T
  }
  public void foo() {
    sneakyThrow(new Exception());
  }
}
```

This compiles, but any reasonable decision as to the actual type of `T` should yield `Throwable`, and require that `foo() throws Throwable`. Eclipse seems to think it's `RuntimeException`. I want to know what `javac` thinks is happening. If it's a bug in `javac`'s processing of type parameters in the `throws` clause, the answer to this question would allow me to prove it.

Comment: It's `Object` in this case.  Can you include an example which you couldn't work out easily yourself?

Comment: BTW Type inference only really occurs in Java 8 and was added to make writing streams/closures easier.  If you don't have Java 8, you don't have type inference.

Comment: @Peter It infers an actual type parameter. Not very strong perhaps but there is some inference happening here.

Comment: It can't be `Object`, it must extend `Throwable`.

Comment: What makes you think Eclipse thinks it's RuntimeException?

Comment: Hover over the invocation and it says its type is `<RuntimeException> void Scratch.sneakyThrow...`

Comment: Why don't you declare the parameter as T instead of Throwable? Then you don't even need the cast.

Comment: I'm more interested in the inference question. But yes, if I wanted to fix the declaration that's absolutely the right thing to do; `T` would be inferred to be Exception and it would correctly fail to compile because checked.

Comment: T would be inferred to extend Throwable actually, and be erased to Throwable. Obviously you've found an Eclipse bug. I'd be astonished if 'javac' shared it. The easiest way to find out would be to write some code that calls it invalidly, e.g. with a String, and check the error message.

Comment: Um, no I doubt it. If you pass an `Exception` to `<T extends Throwable> sneakyThrow(T t)` then `T` will be inferred to be `Exception`. This can be tested more directly, since it does compile if you declare `foo() throws Exception`. In any case, I'm still more interested in getting `javac` to tell me what it thinks.

Comment: What version are you testing this with? Eclipse Juno properly complains about `Throwable` being thrown and does not compile it. The latest, Eclipse Kepler compiles it and seems to find a `RuntimeException`. So this is almost certainly a bug. @PeterLawrey: Type inference was already done (for cases like this) in pre-Java-8 versions. The new feature of Java 8 is the *target* type inference. Concerning the actual question: I doubt that cou can convince javac to provide this kind of information. I'd rather try do do this with http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php , but that's only a first idea

Comment: This compiles on Eclipse Kepler, and also using `javac` 1.7.0_45 and 1.8.0. So you think a regression in Eclipse and a long-standing bug in `javac`?

Comment: The `Scratch` snippet does *not* compile in Eclipse Juno (4.2.1), complaining about "*Unhandled exception type Throwable*" - and to my understanding, this is the correct behavior, for the reasons you mentioned (although I thought it already should have been able to infer that it is not only a `Throwable`, but an `Exception`, but neither of them should compile anyhow)

Comment: Um, no, T is erased at compile time to Throwable, because that's the lower bound. This is Generics, not C++ templates.

Comment: We're not quite talking about the same thing. I'm referring to inference in the sense of JLS 15.12.2.6. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.6 I'm aware of type erasure and the effect that has on what you access at runtime etc., but that happens a stage or two later than this compile-time test.

Comment: Besides that, the sneaky throws are very controversial as they essentially allows checked exceptions to change behavior - they can bubble up through a method not declaring to throw it.  This may be very useful, but may also be very unhelpful to a future maintainer.  I would therefore expect this to be heavily documented to be allowable.

Comment: Absolutely - this is not something I would advocate doing lightly. The question of what the compiler was doing interested me though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to see with a lot of detail what javac has inferred / resolved etc. To do that you need to use the hidden / unsupported / undocumented option: -XDverboseResolution. If one want to see all the information then the value to pass is 'all' as in: -XDverboseResolution=all. If one only want to see the instantiation of the generic methods then the option is: -XDverboseResolution=deferred-inference. For the code in the original question I get the following output:

command: `javac -XDverboseResolution=deferred-inference Scratch.java`

output:

```
Scratch.java:6: Note: Deferred instantiation of method <T>sneakyThrow(Throwable)
    sneakyThrow(new Exception());
               ^
  instantiated signature: (Throwable)void
  target-type: <none>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Throwable declared in method <T>sneakyThrow(Throwable)
Note: Scratch.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

From this output you can infer that T has been instantiated to Throwable.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Hey Vincente, is there any replacement for this (that is production)? The flag doesn't seem to work anymore in JDK 10, and using `-verbose` doesn't display inference information. There is also no `-XX+PrintFlagsFinal` for javac, which can tell me the flags that exist. Right now I'm relying on errors to display inferred types.

Comment: @JornVernee, hi the flag is still there, but it got renamed, this is not part of the API of course. To continue using it you should do:
`javac  --debug=verboseResolution=all`

Comment: You should add the information for new JDKs to the answer. It should not be buried in the comments beneath it.

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is **[type erasure](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3)** as opposed to **type inference**.

I don't know of any option to `javac` which would output type erasure details.

Essentially compiler erases all type parameters to the lowest known type derived from the type parameter:

- `<T>` becomes `Object`
- `<T extends Number>` becomes `Number`
- `<T extends Comparable<T>>` becomes `Comparable`
- `<T extends Cloneable & Comparable<T>>` becomes `Cloneable`
- `<T extends Object & Comparable<T>>` becomes `Object`
- `<S, T extends S>` becomes `Object,Object`

You can always inspect your `.class` file by calling `javap -c <class_name>.class` to see, what is the resulting byte code.

*N.B. Please keep in mind that compiler has various switches allowing you to preserve debug info. See `javac -g` option.

So in terms of experiment below is your code slightly reworked (note type parameter in class declaration and `sneakyThrow(T t) throws T`.

```java
public class Scratch <T extends Throwable> {
  private static <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(T t) throws T {
    throw (T) t;
  }
  public void foo() throws T {
    sneakyThrow((T) new Exception());
  }
}
```

... and below is part of the output of `javap -v -c Scratch.class` after compiling it using `javac -g:none Scratch.java` :

```java
  Constant pool:
  #1 = Methodref          #6.#19     //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
  #2 = Class              #20        //  java/lang/Exception
  #3 = Methodref          #2.#19     //  java/lang/Exception."<init>":()V
  #4 = Methodref          #5.#21     //  Scratch.sneakyThrow:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  #5 = Class              #22        //  Scratch
  #6 = Class              #23        //  java/lang/Object
  #7 = Utf8               <init>
  #8 = Utf8               ()V
  #9 = Utf8               Code
  #10 = Utf8               sneakyThrow
  #11 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  #12 = Utf8               Exceptions
  #13 = Class              #24        //  java/lang/Throwable
  #14 = Utf8               Signature
  #15 = Utf8               <T:Ljava/lang/Throwable;>(TT;)V^TT;
  #16 = Utf8               foo
  #17 = Utf8               ()V^TT;
  #18 = Utf8               <T:Ljava/lang/Throwable;>Ljava/lang/Object;
  #19 = NameAndType        #7:#8      //  "<init>":()V
  #20 = Utf8               java/lang/Exception
  #21 = NameAndType        #10:#11    //  sneakyThrow:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
  #22 = Utf8               Scratch
  #23 = Utf8               java/lang/Object
  #24 = Utf8               java/lang/Throwable

  public Scratch();
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: invokespecial #1      // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return        

  public void foo() throws T;
    Code:
       0: new           #2      // class java/lang/Exception
       3: dup           
       4: invokespecial #3      // Method java/lang/Exception."<init>":()V
       7: invokestatic  #4      // Method sneakyThrow:(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
      10: return        
}
```

As you can see `Throwable` is what **type erasure** settled on.