# Why does a method accept an anonymous generic class object of covariant type?

Tags: java, generics

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        testPairEmployee(new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager()));
    }
    public static void testPairEmployee(Pair<Employee> p) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        p.testFunc();
    }
}
class Employee{}
class Manager extends Employee{}
class Pair<T>{
    private T first;
    private T second;
    public Pair(T first, T second){
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }
    public void testFunc() {
        System.out.println(first.getClass().getName() + '\t' + second.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

The type of `new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager())` is `Pair<Manager>`, why this code can run successfully?

If you think its type is `Pair<Employee>`, but when I wrote this code:

```
testPairEmployee((Pair<Employee>)new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager()));
```

I encountered a compilation error:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast
> 'TestGeneration.Pair<TestGeneration.Manager>' to
> 'TestGeneration.Pair<TestGeneration .Employee>

In other words, the compiler clearly knows that its type is `Pair<Manager>`.

Why?

Comment: Your title question and the question in this code aren't the same

Comment: Sorry, my English is not proficient enough to express this problem in short words. Do you have any good suggestions?

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno The question is clear enough. The intent, at least, is very clear.

Comment: I'd like to make this question more general, not just specific to the `Pair` class, and I don't know what the technical issue is.

Comment: Long story short, you are assuming that generics are covariant. They are not. Please take a look at the answer here, specifically the second half -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666710/why-are-arrays-covariant-but-generics-are-invariant/18666878#18666878 -- The question it is answering is different than yours, but the answer for your question is the same as this answer, specifically the second half.

Comment: Here is an even better answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2745301/697449

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why are Java generics not implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-are-java-generics-not-implicitly-po)

Comment: `new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager())` by *itself* is `Pair<Manager>`, but when assigned to, or used as argument to `Pair<Employee>`, it is inferred as being a `Pair<Employee>`

Comment: None of these answers solved my doubts. I know that generics are not covariant, and the question I asked is exactly a counterexample: method accepts a generic class object of covariant type.

Comment: mm, @davidalayachew - The title has been changed, so yeah, much clearer

Comment: `Pair<Employee> p2 = new Pair<>(new Manager(), new Manager());` = `Pair<Employee> p2 = new Pair<Employee>(new Manager(), new Manager());`. Same reason why the parameter is accepted.

Comment: What 'anonymous class'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The type of new `Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager())` is `Pair<Manager>`

No, it is not. With `javac` 20 we can see the type of the argument using [`--debug=verboseResolution=all`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24284013/make-java-compiler-output-type-inference-information/29442166#comment90865888_29442166):

```
Test.java:3: Note: resolving method testPairEmployee in type Test to candidate 0
        testPairEmployee(new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager()));
        ^
  phase: BASIC
  with actuals: Pair<Employee>
  with type-args: no arguments
  candidates:
      #0 applicable method found: testPairEmployee(Pair<Employee>)
```

As you can see, the type of the argument is `Pair<Employee>`.

---

You can also see that the argument type can not be `Pair<Manager>` because if you provide `Manager` as a type argument explicitly:

```
testPairEmployee(new Pair<Manager>(new Manager(),new Manager()));
```

The code fails to compile:

```
Test.java:3: error: incompatible types: Pair<Manager> cannot be converted to Pair<Employee>
        testPairEmployee(new Pair<Manager>(new Manager(),new Manager()));
                         ^
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error
```

---

As to why you get an error when casting the result of the constructor invocation (as my colleague Dan Smith graciously explained to me): a method invocation appearing in a casting context [is not a poly expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12), which in short means that the type of the cast doesn't affect the inference process, and the type of `new Pair<>(new Manager(),new Manager())` is inferred in isolation to `Pair<Manager>` which can not be cast to `Pair<Employee>`. In other words: the cast is changing the inference process.

Comment: OK, I understand. I try to answer my doubts: 1. `Pair<>` is different from `Pair<Manager>`, it instructs the compiler to infer the type; 2. Since the `testPairEmployee` method declares the parameter type to be `Pair<Employee>`, So the compiler tries to upcast `new Manager()` to type `Employee` so that `new Pair<>(new Manager(), new Manager())` becomes the target type `Pair<Employee>`, obviously , it succeeded. Do you think this explanation is reasonable?

Comment: @KkLee Yes, that's a reasonable to think about it. I would say: the target type of the `new Pair<>(...)` is `Pair<Employee>`, that's easy to infer. And then the two arguments to the constructor `new Manager(), new Manager()` most be assignable to `Employee`, which is also true.

Answer (score 0):

The first snippet works because `Manager` is a subclass of `Employee`, so **it's safe to put a `Manager` object into a reference of type `Employee`**.This concept is known as [covariance](https://web.archive.org/web/20161204181636/https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp07018/index.html).

The error in the second snippet is because of type invariance in generics. In Java, **generics are not covariant**, meaning that you cannot assign a `Pair<Manager>` to a `Pair<Employee>` even if `Manager` is a subclass of `Employee`. This is to **prevent potential runtime errors** because `Pair<Manager>` and `Pair<Employee>` have different generic types, and allowing such assignments could lead to type-related issues.

To make it work, you can use a [`Wildcard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html), this way:

```java
Pair<? extends Employee> p3 = new Pair<>(new Employee(), new Employee());
Pair<Manager> p4 = new Pair<>(new Manager(), new Manager());
p3 = p4; // Now this assignment is valid
```

It ensures that the elements contained in `p3` are always a subclasse of `Employee`.

Check this out:

- [Java generic type issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60248110/java-generic-type-issue)
- [Wildcards and Subtyping](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/subtyping.html)
- [Java generics covariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660827/java-generics-covariance)
- [Covariance, Invariance and Contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481301/covariance-invariance-and-contravariance-explained-in-plain-english)